# How to make datatable specific column editable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

There are various questions put up on this topic but I do not understand them so can anyone help
here is my js code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').toggle();
    var List = [];

    $.ajax({
        url: '/urls/' + id,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: 'data',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("data length: ", data.length);
            console.log("data : ", data);

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                var Logs = {};
                Logs.Info = data[i].Info;
                for (var j = 0; j < Logs.Info.length; j++) {
                    var emplist = {};
                    emplist.Name = Logs.Info[j].Name;
                    emplist.dates = Logs.Info[j].dates;

                    for (var k = 0; k < emplist.dates.length; k++) {
                        var datelist = {};
                        datelist.Name = emplist.Name;
                        datelist.startDate = emplist.dates[k].startDate;
                        datelist.endDate = emplist.dates[k].endDate;
                        List.push(datelist);
                    }
                }

            }


            emptablee = $('#Table').DataTable({
                "data": List,
                "columns": [
                    {"data": "Name"},
                    {"data": "startDate"},
                    {"data": "endDate"},
                ],
                destroy: true,
                "scrollY": "200px",
                "scrollCollapse": true,
                "paging": false
            });
            /*emptablee.destroy();*/
        }

    });
    $("#close").on('click', function () {
        $("#myModal").hide();
    });


});
```

There are three columns in the table and I want to make a specific columns cell-like  editable and show an input box and get the value edited to send.

Comment: use `contenteditable="true"` attribute on those cells. I just replied 20 mins ago to the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54105541/how-to-make-html-table-column-editable?noredirect=1#comment95043446_54105541

Comment: yes i tried it but it make table column's name editable but not column cells

Comment: what? that attribute makes the tag where you use it editable. it does not care where you use it. Move the attribute to the tag that you want to be editable

Comment: <th contenteditable="true" style="text-align: center" class="cell100 column1">Info</th>  It does not work.

Comment: i do not understand what do you want to say. can you please show me hot to do it.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone checking this now, I've created a custom example in which you can make any column editable by just sending it in a metadata request from serverside.

here : https://github.com/sinhashubh/datatable-examples

Answer (score 0):

If you want, for example, your startDate column to be editable, you need to init the Datatables like this so you can hit the column by class name:

```
{"data": "startDate", "className": "editable"},
```

then, with proper event handling

```
// Activate an inline edit on click of a table cell
$('#Table').on( 'click', 'tbody td.editable', function (e) {
    editor.inline( this );
} );
```

and initializing Editor you will be good:

```
editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
    ajax: "../ajax/handle-data.php", // path to back-end data handling
    table: "#Table",
    fields: [ {
            label: "Start Date:",
            name: "startDate"
        }
    ]
} );
```

Also, don't forget to add this outside of document ready handler because you need it as a global var:

```
var editor;
```

Full example here (note that Datatables Editor feature is not free) https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/columns.html

You can also code up your own completely free version, which is slightly more complicated, without using Editor, but still using class names so you can trigger on click events for specific columns.