# How to SendKeys to a div element with coleditable="true" using Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

There is an element I can't figure out how to type text into it.

```
<div class="floatstart gridcell grideditablefield" colname="Items" coltype="string" coleditable="true" val="" style="width: 107px; overflow: hidden; cursor: text; height: 100%;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Without code (manually) in order to put text in it I need to click on it twice, so in the code If I click on the element once, the class seems to change to:

```
<div class="floatstart gridcell grideditablefield activecell"...>&nbsp;</div>
```

And when I click on the element again it changes once more to

```
<div class="floatstart gridcell grideditablefield activecell NDColEditableInEdit"...>&nbsp;</div>
```

Anyway, once I try to send keys to it I get an Error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: 'element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=//doesn't matter)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=//doesn't matter (6a5d10861ce8de5fce22564658033b43cb7de047-refs/branch-heads/4896@{#875}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19042 x86_64)'
```

Code:

```
// It does find the right element
var element = driverReUse.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='CalcOfAmmountsData']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]");
element.Click();
element.Click();
element.SendKeys("keys");
```

Please help

Comment: without a reproductible sample, it will difficult to help you...have you the url of the site?

Comment: @Frenchy the URL of the site is [link](https://ramdor.net/) but you need a user. What do you mean by a reproductible sample?

Comment: there are lot of explanations why sendkeys is not functional..so if you have a sample which reproduces the same problem..it will be easier to bring a solution...and yes its easier with the real site..but here is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Try the below,

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
 act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='CalcOfAmmountsData']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]"))).doubleClick().build().perform();

act.sendKeys('Keys');
```

Please make the changed if any required for `c#`, in above.

Hope this answer your question.

Comment: Tried this, I got no error but it didn't work. it did not fill out the div. Also, it seems like if I fill the tag inside with text, like: `<div>hello</div>` it works, maybe I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Generally *`<div>`* tags are not interactable unless it contains the attribute [**`contenteditable="true"`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52917565/7429447).

---

### Deep Dive

As you mentioned, initially the *`<div>`* element is:

```
<div class="floatstart gridcell grideditablefield" colname="Items" coltype="string" coleditable="true" ...>&nbsp;</div>
```

After first click:

```
<div class="floatstart gridcell grideditablefield activecell" colname="Items" coltype="string" coleditable="true" ...>&nbsp;</div>
```

After second click:

```
<div class="floatstart gridcell grideditablefield activecell NDColEditableInEdit" colname="Items" coltype="string" coleditable="true" ...>&nbsp;</div>
```

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31501109/7429447) and [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54105665/7429447) either after the first or second click an *`<input>`* / *`<textarea>`* gets added, where you need to send the character sequence as follows:

```
// It does find the right element
var element = driverReUse.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='CalcOfAmmountsData']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]");
element.Click();
element.Click();
var input = driverReUse.FindElementByXPath("xpath_input_textarea");
input.SendKeys("keys");
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, very informative. I am sure it is the answer I am looking for, but how do I get the Xpath of that `<input>` / `<textarea>` ? I inspected at the site and I can't seem to find the `<input>` / `<textarea>` element so I can copy it's xpath. Also, Some things that are Indeed changing if I click twice on the div: the 'val' attribute is Changing it's value to the text I'm typing (I am typing it manually not by code), and the innerText is changing also to the text I'm typing.

Comment: Please help....

Comment: Gimme some time

Comment: Alright thanks, if you need more information let me know

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Comment: It says I must have 20 reputation to talk

Comment: @Ilay1242 Yeap, that's true.

Comment: So what am I going to do? is there anyway I can set the 'val' attribute or something?

Comment: Sorry I'm annoying but I really need a solution and nothing is working for me

Comment: @Ilay1242 I wish I could helped you out but I don't have an way either unless you provide more information.

Comment: [Here is a video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s4E-JQX77hdFuKv2Bh1N8RqA4dY-SWE9/view?usp=sharing)  of me inspecting the site, showing the element I want to sendkeys to.